# Laravel5.1: hide a portion of code form view

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-form

Here I've a portion of code which I don't want to show in the user interface.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="customer_id" class="col-sm-4 control-label">{{trans('sale.customer')}}</label>
     <div class="col-sm-8">
          {!! Form::select('customer_id', $customer, Input::old('customer_id'), array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
     </div>
</div>
```

I want this section to be hidden. Laravel form has `form::hidden()` method to do this but how can I apply this in my `form::select()` method.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to hide entire "form-group" div from UI add css property  `style="display:none"` to "form-group" div. and also if you don't want customer_id field in request add `'disabled'=>true` to array of 4th parameter after class.